# ATOM text editor Failed to load init script

Tags: python, atom-editor, init

A while after i set up Atom-editor for the first time, I got a popup saying:

`Failed to load /user/.atom/init.coffee missing / (unclosed regex)`

Didn't give it any attention at first but now i'm trying to customize the init script to make some changes and i can't seem to do that. Any advice on how to get Atom to load the init script?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

As it suggests, the error is stemming from the fact that it's missing a `/` character in the `init.coffee` file. This character is likely required to complete the regex pattern.

If you have edited it, then you may have mixed up `Coffeescript` with `JavaScript` which may also explain the cause of this error. Try to debug the code in the `init.coffee` file and make sure that the code can be correctly compiled.